# Circular Dependency - (how to let struct A refer to struct B, and struct B refer to struct A)

Tags: c++, header, circular-dependency

I have a header file with a struct called Vector4.

(vector4.h)

```
struct Vector4
{
    float Values[4];

    // ..... methods .....
};
```

I have a header file with a struct called Matrix4.

(matrix4.h)

```
struct Matrix4
{
    float Values[16];

    // ..... methods .....
};
```

I want to add a member function to them both, say multiply() which takes the other struct as a parameter.

I can easily add matrix4.h to vector4.h and add the method multiply().

If I then try and add vector4.h to matrix4.h I (obviously) will get a circular reference.

How can I get around this please, if at all?

---

Edit:

@MikeSeymour, I have written what I assumed you meant, but it doesn't work.

bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

template <typename T>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    T t;

    T multiply(const Foo<T>& foo) const;
};

#endif // BAR_H
```

foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

template <typename T>
struct Bar;

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    T t;

    T multiply(const Bar<T>& bar) const;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

bar.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

Bar<T>::multiply(const Foo<T>& foo) const
{
    return t * foo.t;
}
```

foo.cpp

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

Foo<T>::multiply(const Bar<T>& bar) const
{
    return t * bar.t;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to declare each class before the class that needs to refer to it:

```
// vector4.h
struct Matrix4;

struct Vector4
{
    // ...
    void multiply(Matrix4);
};

// matrix4.h
struct Vector4;

struct Matrix4
{
    // ...
    void multiply(Vector4);
};
```

The function definitions, which need full definitions of both classes, will have to be outside the class definitions.

If the classes are actually templates, then those function definitions will have to be in headers, structured so that they appear after both class definitions. One approach is to include each header from the other, *after* that header's definition:

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

template <typename T>
struct Foo;

template <typename T>
struct Bar
{
    T t;

    T multiply(const Foo<T>& foo) const;
};

#include "foo.h"

template <typename T>
T Bar<T>::multiply(const Foo<T>& foo) const
{
    return t * foo.t;
}

#endif // BAR_H
```

Or you might define the functions in separate headers; they'll only be available when you include those headers

```
// bar_multiply.h
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

template <typename T>
T Bar<T>::multiply(const Foo<T>& foo) const
{
    return t * foo.t;
}
```

Or, since the classes are so tightly coupled, you might consider defining both in the same header.

Comment: Ok, but this wouldn't allow me to refer to it's methods, would it?

Comment: No. So you'll have to implement them later (perhaps in source files), once both classes have been fully defined. You won't be able to implement both within their class definitions.

Comment: I am going to return to this when I have time to play with it properly tonight. Both these structs are templated, which changes things, right? I mean, I can't use source files with them.

Comment: @Beakie: Indeed, if they're templates, then the definitions will have to be in headers; you'll have to structure the headers so that both class definitions are included before the function definitions.

Comment: I am unsure how to do this. How can I partially define a struct and then add more definition later (outside of member functions via source files).

Comment: @Beakie: You don't partially define the struct. You fully define it, declaring, but not defining, the member functions in the class definition, as in my example. Then you define those functions outside the class definition, making sure that both classes have been defined before the function definitions.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh. I get ya. Sweet. Will try now. Thanks

Comment: @Beakie: As I said, "if they're templates, then the definitions will have to be in headers; you'll have to structure the headers so that both class definitions are included before the function definitions."

Comment: I WANT to understand what you mean if that helps. Sorry, can you please explain with an example? :-/

Comment: @Beakie: I'm not sure how I can be clearer. I've added some examples which might help.

Comment: Those examples are exactly what I needed. Thanks Mike. Much appreciated +1